# Unregistered SecurityContextSecurityToken on WCF

Tags: wcf, iis-6, windows-server-2003, wcf-security

Does anyone recognise this error?
The SecurityContextSecurityToken with context-id=urn:uuid:xxx (key generation-id=) is not registered

It has suddenly appeared in the service trace log of my WCF service.

We had a Windows service successfully transmitting data into the WCF service for a day until it broke. The error manifests when the Windows service tries to connect to the WCF service.

It's highly unlikely that the environments changed. The two services exist on separate machines (an application server and a web server). Both are Windows Server 2003 SP1 machines, and the web server is running IIS 6.

Unfortunately, we have scarce access to the servers to help us debug, so any guesses on what might be wrong would be highly appreciated.

Indi

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem with Web Service Extension 3.0, which was used before WCF. I have not experianced this with WCF, but I think that it is worth checking.

The scenario works like this:

- The service starts and the user that is the identity of the service gets logged on.
- When the service makes a call it is done in the security context of this user
- After a while the logon token becomes so old (a day?) that the service will no longer accept it.

The easy way to test this is to restart the windows service.

Comment: Restarting the windows service and the two communicate fine. I suppose a fresh logon token is being used. Will have another look after a day.